# Dont know how to correctly edit this code

Tags: c, winapi

Well i am still slightly new in C.

Lets say i have this code:

source.c

```
#include "logger.c"

int main{
FILE *myfile1;
fileX = fopen("myfile.txt, a+);

SetHook(fileX);
}
```

and then i have very simple keylogger
logger.c

```
HHOOK _hook;
KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT kbdStruct;

LRESULT __stdcall HookCallback(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode >= 0)
    {
        if (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN)
        {


            // PRINT INTO THE FILE
            kbdStruct = *((KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam);
            fprintf(fileX, "%c", kbdStruct.vkCode);


        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(_hook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

void SetHook(fileX)
{
    _hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, HookCallback, NULL, 0)
}
```

Basically i want to have separated code like this.

But i think this is wrong i need to pass that "fileX" not to function setHOOK() but to that "LRESULT __stdcall..." and i dont know how to do that.
I will be thankfull for any help.

Comment: do not include source like `#include "logger.c"`, include header file(s)

Comment: @bruno looks promising going to learn something about it thank you :)

Comment: `SetHook` does not accept an argument. Read the code you posted: `void SetHook();`  Where does it say you can pass a `FILE` to it? That `LRESULT __stdcall` isn't expecting a `FILE` either, so it's unclear what you're asking here. You can't just pass a `FILE` to anything you want.

Comment: @KenWhite Yes you are right i forgot to put it in SetHook() in this code but i tried it with it too of course and it didnt work. I just want to have code in seperated files like code up there and printf every logged key in file. I cant place fprintf in SetHook() if i am right it will not work :(

Comment: regarding: `int main{`  This will not compile!   Suggest `int main( void ){`

Comment: regarding this 'signature' for the function: `sethook()`  `void SetHook(fileX)`  Every function parameter must have a 'type'.  Perhaps something similar to: `void SetHook( FILE * fileX )`

Comment: regarding: `_hook`   in C, names beginning with an underscore, should be avoided and if the name begins with an underscore followed by a capital letter, only the system should use such names

Comment: you need a third file: `Logger.h` That contains something similar to: `#ifndef LOGGER_H` then  `#define LOGGER_H`   then all the prototypes needed for the functions in Logger.c then a `extern HHOOK _hook;`  then `#endif // LOGGER_H`  Then each *.c file needs that statement: `#include "Logger.h"`

Comment: @user3629249 Thank you going to try it :)

Comment: You forgot a quote in this line:  `fileX = fopen("myfile.txt, a+);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> WH_KEYBOARD_LL is global hook you need place its hook procedure in a DLL separate from
>   the application installing the hook procedure. (For simple purpose you can put hook procedure in your application and it is also working. But this is not suggested way.)

([SetWindowsHookExA function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa) [Using Hooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/using-hooks))

> This hook is called in the context of the thread that installed it.
>   The call is made by sending a message to the thread that installed the
>   hook. Therefore, the thread that installed the hook must have a
>   message loop. (In another word, the application need have a window so that it can keep pumping messages.)

([LowLevelKeyboardProc callback function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644985%28v=VS.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396))

For learning purpose of hook, my suggestion is getting started using Visual Studio Windows Desktop Application template (C++).

[image]

It is simple to register the keyboard hook and receive message in the hook.

And for writing to a file in the hook producer you can create a named file map so that you don't need to pass a file handle to the hook. You can open this file map using its name and write to the file using this file map. ([Creating Named Shared Memory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/memory/creating-named-shared-memory))

```
static HHOOK hhookKeyPress;

hhookKeyPress = SetWindowsHookEx(
WH_KEYBOARD_LL,
KeyboardHookCallback,
NULL,
0);

// Main message loop:
while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
{
    if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
```

Sharing above information to help you get started and then you can find C programming way later. Hope it helps.